# aframe: how to make dynamically generated entity responsive to user location

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, aframe

How to make the text responsive to user's location e.g. when you walk closer, text gets bigger. You can move "around" the text. (have to enter your longitude and latitude first). I am using mobile device (iphone, chrome).

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-swartz-1b1pbu-jayz-alone-justforcomments-0tbmk7?file=/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-look-at-component@0.8.0/dist/aframe-look-at-component.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-text-geometry-component@^0.5.0/dist/aframe-text-geometry-component.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      a-scene {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  
  <body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden;">
    <a-scene
      vr-mode-ui="enabled: false"
      embedded
      arjs="sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false;"
    >
      <a-assets>
        <img src="WMNH2OF.jpeg" id="chrome" crossorigin="anonymous" />

        <a-asset-item
          id="helvetikerBoldFont"
          src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/fonts/helvetiker_bold.typeface.json"
        ></a-asset-item>
      </a-assets>
      <a-camera gps-camera rotation-reader> </a-camera>
      <!-- <a-camera gps-camera rotation-reader look-controls position="0 1.6 0"> -->
    </a-scene>

    <script>
      let delay = 0;
      let lyrics = [
        "Go shorty",
        "Go shorty",
        "Go shorty",
        "Go shorty",
        "Go shorty",
        "Go shorty"
      ];

   
      function randomRGB() {
        let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
      }

      function createEntity(transcript) {
        let sceneEl = document.querySelector("a-scene");
        let entityEl2 = document.createElement("a-entity");

        entityEl2.setAttribute("gps-entity-place", "latitude:[]; longitude:[]"); 

        entityEl2.object3D.position.set(0, 1.25, -3);
        entityEl2.setAttribute("scale", "1 1 1");
        entityEl2.setAttribute(
          "text-geometry",
          "value: " +
            transcript +
            "; font: #helvetikerBoldFont; bevelEnabled: true; bevelSize: 0.03; bevelThickness: 0.03; curveSegments: 15;"
        );
        entityEl2.setAttribute(
          "material",
          "metalness:0.9; roughness: 0.05; sphericalEnvMap: #chrome; color: " +
            randomRGB()
        );
        // entityEl2.setAttribute("look-at", "[gps-camera]");
        entityEl2.setAttribute(
          "animation",
          "property: position; to: -100, 1.25, -3; dur: 40000; easing: linear;"
        );

        entityEl2.setAttribute(
          "animation__color", // not animation__2
          "property: material.color; to: " +
            randomRGB() +
            "; dur: 2000; easing: linear;"
        );
        sceneEl.appendChild(entityEl2);
      }

      function rap() {
        for (let i = 0; i < lyrics.length; i++) {
          console.log(lyrics[i]);
          setTimeout(function () {
            createEntity(lyrics[i]);
          }, (delay += 2000));
        }
      }

      rap();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your code or the crucial snippets directly in Stack Overflow. Your question should stand on its own two legs without having to follow the external link. Your question should be helpful for others who could have the same problem in the future, so relying solely on external sources can be problematic if the project is deleted from Codesandbox or for other reasons unavailable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've updated the post to include the code